# migration an Maven projet from eclipse to a command line environment

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I got an Maven project which is compiled in Eclipse. Now I need to migrate it to a Linux environment, and there won't be GUI interface I can use.  I wonder what I should do to migrate it?

Currently , under Eclipse project folder I have the files/folders as the below:

- .classpath
- .project
- .settings
- .springBeans
- doc
- pom.xml
- src
- target

I figure all those .* folders are Eclipse meta data. so I can remove them. Then I can use the rest to form a Maven project that I can build using Maven command lines?

Answer (score 1):

For a maven project to work command line, all you need is

1. Maven is installed and correctly exported in the `$PATH` variable
2. The `pom.xml` in your workspace.

Just go to the project directory and run `mvn install`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn clean
```

- then remove `.project` `.classpath`
- if you want to lose eclipse project settings while migrating delete `.settings` (assuming it doesn't have machine specific path/settings)
- copy rest to new linux environment
- open eclipse, import project as maven project (assuming you have new eclipse with maven plugin setup on linux environment)

**Note:**

- make sure you still have a backup before you successfully migrate over
- `.classpath` contains references to local .m2 when used with eclipse and maven so the path would differ in linux and would create issue
- `.project` contains some configuration that is eclipse maven plugin dependent, so it is good to loose it once and let new environment create new one

Comment: So then why would you want to delete `.project` and `.classpath` if you want to open the projects in Eclipse again?

Comment: @Gyro generally .classpath contains references to local `.m2` when used with eclipse and maven so the path would differ in linux and would create issue, I hope it is good enough to make you revert downvote

Comment: Good point, have to check that.  Unfortunately, i cannot undo the downvote, apparently it gets locked-in after only a few minutes. Lesson learned: Better leave a comment and await the discussion than blindly pressing the down button! (Please make an edit so i can revert this).

Comment: I worked a lot with m2e plugin on windows and linux and even in teams with mixed environments and my .classpath files never contain any references to local .m2 folders. There should be no problem keeping .classpath and .project.

Comment: @Volker there is no generally unless you invoke `eclipse:eclipse` goal

Comment: Interesting, thanks for reply, I didn't know. I never used `eclipse:eclipse`yet (and I think I won't).